# Adding button class to table cells <td> that are using html helper

Tags: css, cakephp

There is a table on the admin side of my website that lists tags. There are actions listed next to the tags. The action links are created with html helpers. I am not sure how to properly add the needed class to create buttons instead of links.

Currently adding the class like this:

```
<td class="btn btn-primary"><?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $tag->id, 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?></td>
```

Though this miss aligns the buttons with the header for each column. Not including the class allows the columns to align perfect.

The cookbook show the class being added like this:

```
<td><?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'action' => 'edit', $tag->id]) ?></td>
```

But nothing happens here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I was looking for:

```
<td><?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $tag->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?></td>
```

Its needs separate brackets `,[]` with a comma of course.